# Not specifying type in generic for Swift class

Tags: swift, generics

Let's say we have one protocol:

```
protocol Animal {
}
```

two class which implement this protocol:

```
class Dog: Animal {
}

class Bear: Animal {
}
```

and generic which uses this protocol:

```
class A<T: Animal> {
}
```

Now I can create another classes:

```
class B: A<Dog> {
}

class C: A<Bear> {
}
```

I hope you understand case. And now we have protocol which has instance of class A as parameter:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {

    func something(a: A)
}
```

and I want to implement this protocol in class e.g. D.

```
class D: SomeProtocol {

    func something(a: A) {
    }
}
```

But it won't compile because we have to specify generic for A, how can we do that if we want to send in this parameter instance of class B or C? Can I somehow omit generic in this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I somehow omit generic in this function?

No, you currently cannot talk in terms of a generic type without its placeholder(s). However, you can simply introduce a new local generic placeholder to the function, allowing the placeholder to be satisfied at the call-site.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func something<T>(a: A<T>)
}

class D : SomeProtocol {
    func something<T>(a: A<T>) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the case of passing in an instance of `B`, `T` will be `Dog`. In the case of passing in an instance of `C`, `T` will be `Bear`.

Comment: Oh, right this should work, but I didn't specify exactly what I want in question, and I'm afraid your answer won't work, sorry. I edited question with more details.

Comment: Yeah, I had to check that and it's working, thank you, that's what I wanted! I'm accepting your answer.